My PC no longer runs games
After installing Avast, my games and some Windows applications were no longer working properly. The games in particular were not working. I would run them and the mouse cursor would show that it was loading, but nothing would happen, even in administrator mode. So I used System Restore, going back to a restore point I had created the day before, without imagining that this problem would happen.
The good news is that the Windows applications are no longer having problems, they are working as they should (at least satisfactorily). The bad news is that the games are still not working, and they were working two days ago! Even ePSXe is closing by itself after this, and none of this happened until I installed Avast (which was uninstalled after the restore).
I have already updated the hardware drivers, tried running in compatibility mode, reinstalled OpenGL and DirectX 12, downloaded .Net frameworks and ran them, reinstalled the games and the problem persists. I'm already considering formatting Windows, in case this problem is really serious. I don't know what else to do.
The only games I have that are still working are:

NFS High Stakes;
Tomb Raider (1996) on Glidos;
CS Condition Zero on Steam.

All the others are simply ignored by the OS, without the slightest explanation. However, there are also games that we can consider as retro, such as GTA SA, Sonic Heroes and Assassin's Creed.

And those last games do work, I take it? Perhaps Avast put certain files in quarantine that the non-working games required, like specific DirectX files (which would be highly unlikely, unless they have been toyed with). Just to rule this out: the games that no longer work are legally acquired and not cracked or otherwise changed versions?

is avast actually uninstalled at this point?

Until I installed Avast, I never had this problem. I always downloaded cracked games that only didn't work under specific circumstances, such as bugs. Also, I only downloaded Assassin's Creed, GTA SA and other games as soon as I realized that the ones I had already installed (Sonic Heroes, ePSXe) weren't working. In other words, games that I downloaded after system restore also face this problem.
And Avast is no longer on my PC since I did a system restore.

If it is because some files were removed/quarantined, you'll probably have to reinstall Avast to retrieve them, since they're likely encrypted? https://www.reddit.com/r/antivirus/comments/12xpamb/i_want_to_uninstall_avast_but_i_have_some_concerns/
